# Manually move accessibility focus in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

With Android View, I'm able to move the focus to a View like so:

```
fun View.requestAccessibilityFocus() {
    requestFocus()
    sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
}
```

How do I achieve this in Jetpack Compose?

I tried using FocusRequester but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val requester = FocusRequester()

Box {
    ...
    Image(
        ...
        contentDescription = "My heading",
        modifier = Modifier
            ...
            .focusRequester(requester)
    )
}

DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
         if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
             requester.requestFocus()
         }
    }
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
    onDispose { lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer) }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add `.focusable()` and must do so **after** `.focusRequester(focusRequester)`.

```
Box {
    ...
    Image(
        ...
        contentDescription = "My heading",
        modifier = Modifier
            ...
            .focusRequester(requester)
            .focusable()
    )
}
```

Comment: Note: This solution moves "Focus" not accessibility focus.

Comment: How would one go about moving the accessibility focus then? I've thought that's - in practice - the same thing.

Comment: I'm not entire sure what @MobA11y meant either, the accessibility focus does move when I use this

Comment: It's important for the scenario where the item is Accessibility Focusable, but not Input Focusable. This answer is technically incorrect as it will error in situations where it should not if it achieves the thing the question requested, which is requesting accessibility focus.

This answer is objectively wrong. Either this answer or the question would need to change for technical accuracy. Even though it works most of the time and in most situations where it matters. Ex: A stupid thing this might lead to would be forcing a pure text element to be input focusable.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `DiposableEffect` might be calling during recomposition. You should not request focus during composition. The solution I have found is to request a focus right after the composition. Like this

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        this.coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
```

This makes sure your code will run when the LauchedEffect leaves the composition because it(the coroutine) either got canceled or completed.

Comment: Did you get it working in a Edit Text component? I tried `Handler().postDelayed({ requester.requestFocus() }, 500)` with this and it still wouldn't move the focus.

Comment: It worked for me for TextField component using SideEffects. Did you try remember { FocusRequester() }